# как поместить куки в класс php

Tags: php, ооп, cookie

```
class Client
{

    private $client_cookies = $_COOKIE;

}
```

я получаю ошибку ,как поместить куки в класс php правильно ?

Comment: А какую ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public function setCookie($cookie)
    {
        $this->client_cookies = $cookie;
    }

    public function getCookie()
    {
        return $this->client_cookies;
    }
```